# Oracle Global Temporary table (GTT)

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

Can some one please help me to find of the answer for this?

Assume a situation that, you have created a GTT with the 100 records from Region 1 (Region may be a different db,schema..) and 50 records from Region 2.

What technique should be applied here to preserve only the 100 records I have loaded from the region 1 and not the region 2?

Comment: so you have a GTT and you've done two inserts into it in the same session, but after committing, you only want to keep one set of the rows? If so, then `DELETE from your_gtt where <condition that identies rows that were in region 2>`. If not, please update your question with the GTT creation script, sample data insert statements, and the required output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please post what you have tried so far.